Python Automation: Loop not working properly
Thank you all for your generous help. I am still new to programming and I have some trouble automating data entry from Excel sheet to a third-party software.

For the excel sheet, it is very straight forward with 3 columns:
ROW1    Item ID | Customer Name | Order ID
ROW2    0872    | Hello         | 89182
ROW3    0981    | World         | 78192
...........

What I need to do is go into the software, search by item ID, and add the order ID under a very specific section.
Since the vendor does not give me the back end access, I decided to use pyautogui to automate clicking and data entry.
To prevent python from reading the first row and go indefinitely, I defined:
start_row = 2
end_row = 2000 # Hypothetical end

However, it only processes the 2000th row by skipping 1-1999th rows.
It only works when I run the code for single line as:
start_row = 2
end_row = 2
And it processes Row 2
Below is my code:
import pyautogui
import time
import openpyxl
import keyboard

# currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position()

# print(currentMouseX, currentMouseY) # To find mouse cordinates for desired fields + Buttons

# Grab the data from the Excel workbook

file_path="D:/User/Documents/Order ID Edit/Recent_Transactions.xlsx"
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook (file_path)
wsheet = workbook.active

start_row = 2
end_row = 2000

pyautogui.click (806,747) # Software icon on taskbar, I need to log in and go to logistic   section, but it only needs me to do it once so I didn't automate this.

# Inside the software:

# To Search

pyautogui.click(305,59) # Click search icon
pyautogui.doubleClick(301,95) # Click box for search

# Grab Item ID from Excel in certain range:

for i in range(start_row, end_row + 1):
  j = 1
  ItemID = wsheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value
pyautogui.write(ItemID)
keyboard.send('Enter')

# Edit Order ID:

pyautogui.doubleClick (357,560) #Click on Order ID
for i in range(start_row, end_row + 1):
  j = 3
  OrderID = wsheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value
pyautogui.write(OrderID)
keyboard.send('Enter')

# Save all edits:

pyautogui.click(355,64) # Click Edit Icon
pyautogui.click(371,64) # Click Save Icon


You have somehow managed to lose all indentation when you pasted your code here, which in the case of Python makes it impossible to tell what the code actually does - we can't tell what's inside and what's outside of a loop, for example.

As far as can be determined, notwithstanding the lack of code indentation, the code will loop through rows 2 to 2000 for columns A then B and writes the cell values to an unknown app. If you are only seeing the last row processed whether it be set to 2 or 2000 it's probably to do with the app receiving the cell value.
